# Center a div within a div

Tags: html, center

I have been having trouble centering a div within a div. I got these radio buttons lined up fine, but can't get the image to line up under the buttons.  Look online but can't find a solution.

Here's what I have now.

```css
.fieldgroup {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style='text-align:center;'>
  <div class='fieldgroup'>
    <div style='z-index: 2; position: relative; left: 68px; top: 10px;'>
      <input type='radio' id='star' name='rating' value='1'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='fieldgroup'>
    <div style='z-index: 2; position: relative; left: 118px; top: 10px;'>
      <input type='radio' id='star' name='rating' value='2'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='fieldgroup'>
    <div style='z-index: 2; position: relative; left: 169px; top: 10px;'>
      <input type='radio' id='star' name='rating' value='3'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='fieldgroup'>
    <div style='z-index: 2; position: relative; left: 219px; top: 10px;'>
      <input type='radio' id='star' name='rating' value='4'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='fieldgroup'>
    <div style='z-index: 2; position: relative; left: 269px; top: 10px;'>
      <input type='radio' id='star' name='rating' value='5' checked>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='fieldgroup'>
    <div style='z-index: 2; position: relative; top: 25px;'>
      <br><img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='position:relative;top:50px;'>
    <button type='submit' name='submit'>Rate Rider</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to do all thing center of the page?

Comment: yes....it's a form on website that can be accessed by phones.  Everything must be centered horizontally.  Radio buttons, 5 star pic, then form button at bottom.

Comment: What's the point of a single image with five stars? Shouldn't the star color correlate with the checkbox status?

Comment: Yes, Isherwood, the star correlation should match the star, but I am only a beginner coder and don't have that ability yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `justify-center` property.

#### Center a div:

```css
.center {
  border: 5px solid #FFFF00;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <p>The text within the div is centered horizontally.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, that only fixed half the problem.  Thanks for your reply. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of hard-coded position styles is a poor way to align anything, and is unlikely to work well on various screen sizes.

Instead, we can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to space the radio buttons out across a container element that has the width of the image. This makes everything automatic.

Other notes:

- Duplicate IDs are invalid. IDs must be unique. I'm not sure what they were for, but they aren't needed here and any script relying on them will probably have bugs.
- Don't use line breaks for layout spacing. That's a misuse of the element. Instead, use margin or padding.
- Don't use inline styles. They're a pain to work with and a pain to maintain if you make changes later. Use classes.
- Double-quotes for HTML, single for JavaScript is a good way to avoid confusion. You generally won't have to escape any quotes in your scripts.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: min-content;
  background: pink;
}

.fieldgroups {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* make width calculations include padding */
  padding: 0 8px 0 1px; /* match goofy spacing at edges of the image */
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fieldgroups">
    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='1'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='2'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='3'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='4'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='5' checked>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
  </div>

  <button type='submit' name='submit'>Rate Rider</button>
</div>
```

If you decide to move to using individual images, you can set that up in a similar way.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: pink;
}

.fieldgroups {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.fieldgroup {
  min-width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.fieldgroup img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  /* would be better to use single star images, but we'll fake it */
  width: 22px;
  height: 20px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fieldgroups">
    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='1'>
      <img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='2'>
      <img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='3'>
      <img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='4'>
      <img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
    </div>

    <div class='fieldgroup'>
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='5' checked>
      <img src='https://localrides.net/images/star.jpg'>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type='submit' name='submit'>Rate Rider</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you isherwood much appreciated for your efforts. For some reason the radio buttons still won't line up for me, but I will keep playing around with it.  Can you tell me what css adjusts the radio button spacing and how to adjust that?

Comment: I found by reducing the width to 85% made the radio buttons line up with my star image.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, but please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site.